# System.InvalidOperationException: 'There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'items'.'

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Im new to c# and am trying to make a simple MVC Web Application
///This is create.cshtml

```
<div class="form-group">
    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.MembershipID, "MembershipID", htmlAttributes: new 
    { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
    <div class="col-md-10">
       @Html.DropDownList("items",ViewData["items"] as IEnumerable<SelectListItem>, new { @class 
    = "form-control" })
       @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.MembershipID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" 
      })
    </div>
</div>
```

and this is my Student Controller

```
public ActionResult Create()
{
     List<SelectListItem> items = new List<SelectListItem>();
     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Day", Value = "0" });
     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Month", Value = "1" });
     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Direct-Debit", Value = "2" });
     items.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = "Other", Value = "3" });

     ViewData["MembershipID"] = items;
     return View();
}

[HttpPost] 
public ActionResult Create(Student student) { 
    try { // TODO: Add insert logic here 
        using (BlackBeardDBEntities db = new BlackBeardDBEntities()) { 
            db.Students.Add(student); 
            db.SaveChanges(); 
        } 
        return RedirectToAction("Index"); 
     } catch { 
        return View(); 
     } 
}
```

Comment: Make sure the ViewData keys match. You have `ViewData["MembershipID"]` in the controller and `ViewData["items"]` in the view

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of things:

As mentioned in the comments, change your `ViewData["MembershipID"] = items;` to `ViewData["items"] = items;` in your `Controller` method

Secondly: You need to display the `selectlist` item as:

```
@Html.DropDownList("items",ViewData["items"] as List<SelectListItem>, new { @class="form-control" })
```

Answer (score 0):

`ViewData["items"]` is not declared in the controller. To access that data you need to Change

```
@Html.DropDownList("items",ViewData["items"]
```

To

```
@Html.DropDownList("items",new SelectList((IEnumerable<SelectListItem>) ViewData["MembershipID"])
```

Comment: I still get the error:There is no ViewData item of type 'IEnumerable<SelectListItem>' that has the key 'items'.'

Comment: Try with the updated code. Also check your Html for another `ViewData["items"]` reference

Comment: Now am getting the error:IEnumerable interface exposes the enumerator, which supports a simple iteration over a non-generic collection. : IEnumerable

Comment: Sorry, I missed the type.

Comment: Now im getting this error when i click create: System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: items'

Comment: Can you share the code for the click button? I'm missing information here.

Comment: [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Student student)
        {
            try
            {

                // TODO: Add insert logic here
                using (BlackBeardDBEntities db = new BlackBeardDBEntities())
                {
                    db.Students.Add(student);
                    db.SaveChanges();
                }
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            catch
            {
                return View();
            }
        }

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207107/discussion-between-ichigo-kurosaki-and-athanasios-kataras).

Answer (score 0):

In you controller you are declaring ViewData as **ViewData["MembershipId"]** and in view you are using **ViewData["items"]** that is wrong . Make sure that the key of you ViewData is same in both cases.
In controller,replace ViewData["MembershipId"] with ViewData["items"].
Also ,you are storing data in viewdata as **List** and using in view as  **IEnumerable** .
Make changes in it and then try to build.